# Javascript for replacing text on Wikia site

Tags: javascript, text, replace, wikia

I want to use some JS Scripts to replace some bad words automatically on my Wikia site. Here my code:

```
$(function () {
    var str = document.getElementById("WikiaPage").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/badword1/gi, "beep").replace(/badword2/gi, "beep");
    document.getElementById("WikiaPage").innerHTML = res;
});
```

Then it works. But this code causes crash on Wikia Comments Section, Recent Wiki Section in WIkia Rail and some issues may I don't know yet.

How can i do now? Any help is appreciated. Thank everyone.

Comment: These sections doesn't show after many Ctrl F5

Comment: Resetting `innerHTML` removes all the events handlers. That's probably what's happening in that document. Try with filtering the `textNode`s and replacing their `nodeValue` property instead.

Comment: Can you tell me more details what exactly I have to change this code. Sorry if I've troubled you. Thank you for helping me. ^ ^

Comment: No problem. Please read [this blog post](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-its-not-that-simple/). The author also has created a library that does what you want.